# ASP MVC Post Encoding Shift-Jis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, shift-jis

I have a form that is sits in a plain .html file with the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
```

The service I'm posting a form to requires that the data is in shift-jis encoding. When I post this form by just opening this .html file with Chrome, then clicking a submit button, the service accepts it fine. When I inspect the post values in Fiddler, the Japanese characters appear in the post to the service like follows:

`goods_name_1 = "���i�P"`

Now when I take the exact same form and place it in an ASP MVC view, serve the view to Chrome with its source identical to the one I have in the .html file, view source looks exactly the same as the .html version opened did. But the problem is when I post the form with a submit button, the post values look like this:

`goods_name_1 = "商品１"`

The service then replies with an encoding issue.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong? The view served from ASP MVC has the response header "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8". Im not sure why the post values aren't the same as the .HTML file version though. Any ideas?

Just to add, the .html file I have is saved as Unicode in windows.

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding headers in the response (Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "charset=shift_jis";)?

Comment: Are you setting culture? 

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ContentEncoding of the response either in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis");
    return View();
}
```

Or in the View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis");
}
```